# IsoDep Card using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, rfid

I'm trying to interact with a NFC Card (IsoDep) using a raspberry pi.
I built an Android app just fine to connect to this card but now as I am trying to build the python side, I am struggling to find a library to manage isodep. I am running tests using nfcpy, not running smoothly with ACR122U reader.

Please, has anyone built a python app to interact with IsoDep NFC Cards? With which lib?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok my question was a bit off, now I've discovered more on this topic, still not an expert, but here is what helped me:

I ended up using "pyscard 1.9.9"

I found many clues in the [reader doc](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf) (not easily provided by the manufacturer).

It does work but not completely following the Manuf Doc, hence if you're stuck with direct transmits just try running them with no header, it works for me.